# Method to determine a person's city/state using location coordinates?

Tags: gps

I am working on data-mining project where I have to map a bunch of tweets to US states. I can get the lat/long coordinates from the tweet json, but I am not sure if it is possible to map those coordinates to a state? Does anybody have idea/approach to how to approach the problem? Is there any service which I can use for my project? or a database which maps coordinates to US states?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [turf.inside](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_inside.html) from [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/). To be able to use Turf you would need to convert your tweet JSONs into GeoJSONs and then you would also need a GeoJSON of the states, which is [easily found](http://eric.clst.org/Stuff/USGeoJSON) with a simple online search.

[Here](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-inside/) is an example that is very similar to what you are looking for. All you would have to add is a loop to iterate through your States to check individually whether your tweet falls into the State or not. I would break out of the loop once your point proves to be within a State, so the entire process is sped up.

The general syntax for your example would be:

```
turf.inside(tweet, state);
```